# Cauchy sequence and metrics

Tags: convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

I'm having trouble with another analysis homework problem:

Let $x_n$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $d(x_n, x_{n+1}) \le \frac{d(x_{n-1},x_n)}{2}$. Show that $x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence.

I know that I need to prove that for any $\epsilon$ there exists a $N$ such that $m,n \ge N$ implies $d(x_m,x_n) < \epsilon$. However, I am having a hard time defining this $N$. Here is what I have so far:

$$d(x_n, x_{n+1}) \le \frac{d(x_{n-1},x_n)}{2} \le d(x_{n-1},x_n) \le d(x_{n-1},x_{\lambda}) + d(x_{\lambda}, x_n).$$

Now, if I can show that for any $\epsilon$, there exists a $N_1$ such that $m,n \ge N_1$ implies $d(x_m,x_n) < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and for any epsilon, there exists a $N_2$ such that $p,q \ge N_2$ implies $d(x_p,x_q) < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$, then I can simply define $N = \max\{N_1,N_2\}$ and I am done. Unfortunately, I do not know how to go about finding $N_1$ and $N_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give it a shot. Fix $\epsilon>0$. Let $N$ be such that $\frac{d(x_{0},x_{1})}{2^{N}}<\epsilon$. Then, for $n,m > N+1$, we have $m=n+k$ for some positive $k$ and:

$$
d(x_{n},x_{m})\leq d(x_{n},x_{n+1})+\ldots+d(x_{m-1},x_{m}) \leq \frac{d(x_{0},x_{1})}{2^{n}} + \frac{d(x_{0},x_{1})}{2^{n+1}} + \ldots + \frac{d(x_{0},x_{1})}{2^{n+k-1}} \\
\leq d(x_{0},x_{1})\frac{1}{2^{n}}(\frac{1-(1/2)^{k}}{1/2}) = d(x_{0},x_{1})\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}({1-(1/2)^{k}}) \leq \frac{d(x_{0},x_{1})}{2^{n-1}} < \epsilon
$$

since $n >N+1$. I think this is it, but feel free to judge my answer.

Comment: Yea I think this is largely correct. I may be wrong, but I did not follow the second to last step in your chain of inequalities. Namely, $d(x_0,x_1)\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}(1-(1/2)^k) \le \frac{d(x_0,x_1)}{2^n}$. Here is my approach:

$(1-(1/2)^k) = 1 - \frac{1}{2^k} = \frac{2^k -1}{2^k} = \frac{2^{m-n}-1}{2^{m-n}} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}(1-(1/2)^k) = \frac{2^{m-n}-1}{2^{m-1}}$

Comment: I think you made a slight algebra mistake, from the last expression, we can rewrite as $\frac{2^{m-n}-1}{2^{m-1}} = \frac{2^m - 1}{2^n(2^{m-1})}$. We cannot however cancel the $2^m$ and $2^{m-1}$ as there is a $-1$ in the numerator.

Comment: Yeah, it was wrong, I edited. We have $\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}(1-(1/2)^{k}) \leq \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$, since $k \geq 0$, which means that $(1-(1/2)^{k}) \leq 1$. We have then, to assume n-1>N. Is this correct?

Comment: Yea, I just added the requirement that $m,n \ge N+1$. This means $n \ge N+1 \iff n-1\ge N$.